# H2O interprets unary operator "-x" as "1-x" instead of "0-x"

Tags: r, h2o

H2O returns wrong results when applying the unary "-" operator.

If we take a vector with different real values and calculate "-U", "0-U" and "1-U"

```
require(h2o)
h2o.init()

set.seed(5988765)
u = runif(10,-1,1)
u[1] = 0
u[2] = 1
u[3] = -1
U = as.h2o(u)
uU = data.frame(
  u = u,
  U = as.data.frame(U)[,1],
  `0-U` = as.data.frame(0-U)[,1],
  `-U` = as.data.frame(-U)[,1],
  `1-U` = as.data.frame(1-U)[,1]
)
colnames(uU)=c("u","U","0-U","-U","1-U")
print(uU)
```

then we obtain this table, where -U is equal to 1-U instead of 0-U

```
            u          U        0-U        -U       1-U
1   0.0000000  0.0000000  0.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000
2   1.0000000  1.0000000 -1.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
3  -1.0000000 -1.0000000  1.0000000 2.0000000 2.0000000
4  -0.7438718 -0.7438718  0.7438718 1.7438718 1.7438718
5   0.1917035  0.1917035 -0.1917035 0.8082965 0.8082965
6   0.3603398  0.3603398 -0.3603398 0.6396602 0.6396602
7  -0.7400701 -0.7400701  0.7400701 1.7400701 1.7400701
8  -0.4906903 -0.4906903  0.4906903 1.4906903 1.4906903
9   0.3773852  0.3773852 -0.3773852 0.6226148 0.6226148
10  0.1957617  0.1957617 -0.1957617 0.8042383 0.8042383
```

My H2O version is

```
> h2o.getVersion()
[1] "3.32.0.1"
```

Comment: Are you looking for a workaround, or confirmation about whether it's a bug? It looks like the problem is that `-U` does not do the same as `-1*U`. Without knowing much about the package, I can't say whether that's a bug or intentional behaviour (it certainly seems odd though). The problem's unrelated to the exponential function though.

Comment: Thank you @miff, indeed, the problem is in monary operator "-U" which is interpreted as "1-U" instead of "0-U". 

It is clear to me that it is a bug, probably in the parser or in some step in the communication between R and the H2O Java code.

Comment: I've open a ticket in H2O Backlog

https://h2oai.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-7990

Comment: Thank you @Konrad for your corrections, and sorry for my poor English.